# Analyzing final value given changing x values through time

Tags: time-series

I am analyzing data that contains the Y variable (final chemical content of a plant when it was harvested ~ 8 weeks) and the explanatory x variables of light quality measured each week for 8 weeks. I understand that this is not a typical time series analysis because my y value is not measured at each of these intervals but rather only at week 8, but I want to see how the changes throughout the 8 weeks influences the final chemical concentration. One possibility would be a nested regression where treatments (categorical) would have the light measurements (numerical) nested within them for each week. However, I'm not sure if this is the best approach. Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not coding related

Comment: Ilse, you should post your question [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) at SO sister site stats.

Comment: An example of your dataset is more than welcome once you moved question. I assume your chemical production is more or less constant over these 8 weeks. Any day/night light schedule to take into account? Provide that answer as additional info into your question.

Comment: ZF007 - thanks, I'll move the question over to stack exchange